# How do you add iterations from multiple functions

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
outstanding_shares = get_class_i(f) + get_class_c(f) + get_class_i(f)
```

I'm a bit of a noob. I'm trying to understand how to add each of these functions together iteration by iteration. Instead, I just get one big output. The idea would be to get the outstanding shares day by day over a month with the end result being a line graph.

```
def get_class_a(d):
    cs = 0

    excel_file = 'nav/Catalyst_Exceed_Port_daily_nav' + d +'.xls'
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file, logfile=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    df = pd.read_excel(wb)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        if (row[0] == 'CATALYST/EXCEED DEFINED SHIELD FUND Class A'):
            cs = row[7]
    return cs

c = 0
for f in ('20200102', '20200103', '20200106', '20200107', '20200108', '20200109', '20200110',
          '20200113', '20200114', '20200115', '20200116', '20200117', '20200121', '20200122',
          '20200123', '20200124', '20200127', '20200128', '20200129', '20200130', '20200131'):
    #print(get_class_a(f), end=", ")

    print()
#########Grabbing Class C Shares Outstanding
def get_class_c(d):
    cs = 0

    excel_file = 'nav/Catalyst_Exceed_Port_daily_nav' + d +'.xls'
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file, logfile=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    df = pd.read_excel(wb)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        if (row[0] == 'CATALYST/EXCEED DEFINED SHIELD FUND Class C'):
            cs = row[7]
    return cs

c = 0
for f in ('20200102', '20200103', '20200106', '20200107', '20200108', '20200109', '20200110',
          '20200113', '20200114', '20200115', '20200116', '20200117', '20200121', '20200122',
          '20200123', '20200124', '20200127', '20200128', '20200129', '20200130', '20200131'):
    #print(get_class_c(f), end=", ")

    print()
#########Grabbing Class I Shares Outstanding
def get_class_i(d):
    cs = 0

    excel_file = 'nav/Catalyst_Exceed_Port_daily_nav' + d +'.xls'
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file, logfile=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    df = pd.read_excel(wb)

    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        if (row[0] == 'CATALYST/EXCEED DEFINED SHIELD FUND Class I'):
            cs = row[7]
    return cs

c = 0
for f in ('20200102', '20200103', '20200106', '20200107', '20200108', '20200109', '20200110',
          '20200113', '20200114', '20200115', '20200116', '20200117', '20200121', '20200122',
          '20200123', '20200124', '20200127', '20200128', '20200129', '20200130', '20200131'):
    #print(get_class_i(f), end=", ")
    print()



outstanding_shares = get_class_i(f) + get_class_c(f) + get_class_i(f)

print(outstanding_shares, end=", ")
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need any loops in this code at all.

Comment: e.g., `cs = df.at[lambda x: x.iloc[:, 0] = f'CATALYST/EXCEED DEFINED SHIELD FUND Class {letter}', <column name>]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```py
import pandas

datestrings = [
    '20200102', '20200103', '20200106', '20200107', '20200108', '20200109', '20200110',
    '20200113', '20200114', '20200115', '20200116', '20200117', '20200121', '20200122',
    '20200123', '20200124', '20200127', '20200128', '20200129', '20200130', '20200131'
]

# compile all of the data
data = pandas.concat([
    pandas.read_excel('nav/Catalyst_Exceed_Port_daily_nav' + d +'.xls')
    for d in datestrings
], ignore_index=True)

# create all list of the valid values of the first column
classes_you_want = [
    f'CATALYST/EXCEED DEFINED SHIELD FUND Class {letter}'
    for letter in ('A', 'C', 'I')
]

# select all of the rows where the first column has a valid value,
# then select the 8th column, take the sum
outstanding_shares = (
    data.loc[data.iloc[:, 0].isin(classes_you_want)]
        .iloc[:, 7]
        .sum()
)
```

Ideally, instead of `iloc`, you'd use `.loc` and provide actual column labels. This is good because pandas aligns the columns during the concatenation. So even if the order is insistent in your spreadsheets, pandas will shuffle things around and you won't have to keep track of *where* columns are, only what they are called.

Also, if you want to grab all of the Excel files in your directory, you can avoid typing out the `datestring` list with the following:

```py
from pathlib import Path

datadir = Path('nav')
data = pandas.concat([
    pandas.read_excel(xlfile)
    for xlfile in datadir.glob('Catalyst_Exceed_Port_daily_nav*.xls')
], ignore_index=True)
```